# How do calculate the constant c of the Midpoint algorithm?

Tags: geometry, algorithms

I hope this is a question for this community.

I consider the Midpoint algorithm for a line as known.

We have the following funktion:
$g(x+1,y+\frac{1}{2})=\Delta y*(x+1)-\Delta x*(y+\frac{1}{2}) + c$, $c=\Delta y*x_1-\Delta x*y_1$

Where $\Delta x = x_2-x_1$ and $\Delta y = y_2-y_1$

Lets have a line between points $P_1(x_1,y_1)=P_1(100,5)$ and $P_2(x_2,y_2)=P_2(107,9)$ the goal is to calculate the rasterization or better the pixels between does two point on the line.

If $g(x+1,y+\frac{1}{2}) > 0$ then we draw $pixel(x+1,y+1)$ else $pixel(x+1,y)$.

But if we take a look at the constant $c$ then I don't see how we ever get $g(...)\leq 0$, because $c$ would be
$c=\Delta y*x_1-\Delta x*y_1 = 4*100 - 7*5 = 365$ way to big.

So the question is, where am I wrong, because i have to be worong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is
$$\begin{aligned}
g(x,y) & = \Delta_y x - \Delta_x y + c \\
c & = \Delta_y x_1 - \Delta_x y_1 \\
\Delta_x & = x_2 - x_1 \\
\Delta_y & = y_2 - y_1 \\
\end{aligned}$$
Expanding it we get
$$\begin{aligned}
g(x,y) & = (y_2 - y_1) x - (x_2 - x_1) y + (y_2 - y_1) x_1 - (x_2 - x_1) y_1 \\
     ~ & = (y_2 - y_1) (x - x_1) - (x_2 - x_1) (y - y_1) \\
\end{aligned}$$
Note how $g(x_1, y_1) = 0$ and $g(x_2, y_2) = 0$?

If we use $0 \le \lambda \le 1$ to interpolate linearly between $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$, i.e. the line between the two points, using
$$\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
x = (1 - \lambda) x_1 + \lambda x_2 &= x_1 + \lambda (x_2 - x_1) \\
y = (1 - \lambda) y_1 + \lambda y_2 &= y_1 + \lambda (x_2 - x_1) \\
\end{aligned}\right.$$
we get
$$\begin{aligned}
g(\lambda) &= (y_2 - y_1) \lambda (x_2 - x_1) - (x_2 - x_1) \lambda (y_2 - y_1) \\
~          &= (x_2 - x_1) \lambda (y_2 - y_1) - (x_2 - x_1) \lambda (y_2 - y_1) \\
~          &= 0 \\
\end{aligned}$$

---

Let's examine the case where $(x_1, y_1) = (100, 5)$ and $(x_2, y_2) = (107, 9)$.  Now,
$$\begin{aligned}
\Delta_x = x_2 - x_1 = 107 - 100 &= 7 \\
\Delta_y = y_2 - y_1 = 9 - 5 &= 4 \\
c = \Delta_y x_1 - \Delta x y_1 &= 365 \\
\end{aligned}$$
Note that $\Delta_x \gt \Delta_y$.  This means the line is closer to horizontal than vertical, and at every step $x$ increases by one. The rule for mostly horizontal lines, $x_2 \ge x_1$, and $x_2 - x_1 \ge y_2 - y_1 \ge 0$, is
$$\text{if } g\left(x + 1, y + \frac{1}{2}\right) \ge 0, \text{ draw } (x + 1, y), \text{ else draw } (x + 1, y + 1)$$

First pixel is $(x_1, y_1)$, and we always draw that.

Because $g\left(x_1 + 1, y_1 + \frac{1}{2}\right) = -\frac{1}{2}$, we draw $(x_1 + 1, y_1 + 1)$.

Because $g\left(x_1 + 2, y_1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{5}{2}$, we draw $(x_1 + 2, y_1 + 1)$.

Because $g\left(x_1 + 3, y_1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2}\right) = -\frac{3}{2}$, we draw $(x_1 + 3, y_1 + 2)$.

Because $g\left(x_1 + 4, y_1 + 2 + \frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{3}{2}$, we draw $(x_1 + 4, y_1 + 2)$.

Because $g\left(x_1 + 5, y_1 + 2 + \frac{1}{2}\right) = -\frac{5}{2}$, we draw $(x_1 + 5, y_1 + 3)$.

Because $g\left(x_1 + 6, y_1 + 3 + \frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{2}$, we draw $(x_1 + 6, y_1 + 3)$.

Because $g\left(x_1 + 7, y_1 + 3 + \frac{1}{2}\right) = -\frac{7}{2}$, we draw $(x_1 + 7, y_1 + 4)$.

We realize that $x_1 + 7 = x_2$ (and $y_1 + 4 = y_2$), so we arrived where we should have.  Line drawn.

---

All eight octants (divided by lines $x = 0$, $y = 0$, $y = x$, and $y = -x$) have their own rule, but if we swap the line endpoints when necessary, we only need to deal with four of them.  The logic is as follows:

- If $x_1 = x_2$ and $y_1 = y_2$, the line is only a single point.

  Otherwise,
- If $y_1 = y_2$, the line is horizontal.  Draw from $x = \min(x_1, x_2)$ to $x = \max(x_1, x_2)$ at $y = y_1 = y_2$.

  Otherwise,
- If $x_1 = x_2$, the line is vertical.  Draw from $y = \min(y_1, y_2)$ to $y = \max(y_1, y_2)$ at $x = x_1 = x_2$.

  Otherwise,
- If $\lvert x_2 - x_1 \rvert \ge \lvert y_2 - y_1 \rvert$, the line is mostly horizontal.

  Otherwise, the line is mostly vertical.

When the line is mostly horizontal, make sure $x_1 \lt x_2$ (swapping the endpoints if necessary; remember to update $c$, $\Delta_x$, and $\Delta_y$). Then, if $y_2 \gt y_1$, the rule is
$$\text{if } g\left(x + 1, y + \frac{1}{2}\right) \ge 0, \text{ draw } (x + 1, y), \text{ else draw } (x + 1, y + 1)$$
Otherwise, for a mostly horizontal line, $y_2 \lt y_1$, and the rule is
$$\text{if } g\left(x + 1, y - \frac{1}{2}\right) \ge 0, \text{ draw } (x + 1, y), \text{ else draw } (x + 1, y - 1)$$

When the line is mostly vertical, make sure $y_1 \lt y_2$ (swapping the endpoints if necessary; remember to update $c$, $\Delta_x$, and $\Delta_y$). Then, if $x_2 \gt x_1$, the rule is
$$\text{if } g\left(x + \frac{1}{2}, y + 1\right) \ge 0, \text{ draw } (x, y + 1), \text{ else draw } (x + 1, y + 1)$$
Otherwise, for a mostly vertical line, $x_2 \lt x_1$, and the rule is
$$\text{if } g\left(x - \frac{1}{2}, y + 1\right) \ge 0, \text{ draw } (x, y + 1), \text{ else draw } (x - 1, y + 1)$$

In both mostly horizontal line cases and both mostly vertical line cases, we start with $x = x_1$ and $y = y_1$, and draw pixel $(x, y)$.

Mostly horizontal lines loop for as long as $x \lt x_2$, and mostly vertical lines loop for as long as $y \lt y_2$.